# Calling the trigger by class Method

Tags: class, helper

I write a trigger on case for avoiding duplicate case by updating case status to "Duplicate". This Duplicate is manually inserted in picklist.
I have to write Helper & Test class for this.

**Class**

```
public class CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus1
{
   public set<string> setSubject = new set<string>();
   public List<string> ExistedCase = new List<string>();
   public List<string> InsertExistingCase = new List<string>();

    public void CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus(List<case> newCase)
    {
        for (case c:newcase) {
            setSubject.add(c.Subject);
        }

        List<case> ExistedCaseRecords =[select ID,subject from case where subject in :setsubject];

        for (case c :ExistedCaseRecords)  {
            InsertExistingCase.add(c.subject);
        }

        for (case c :newcase) {
            If (InsertExistingCase.contains(c.subject)) {
                c.status='Duplicate';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Trigger**

```
trigger CaseDuplicate on Case (Before Insert) {
        CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus1 helper = new CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus1();
        helper.CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus(setSubject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a handler class here, `CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus1`. While you aren't following a defined handler pattern, this class is playing the *role* of a handler class for this trigger by encapsulating all of the business logic.

Naming your one method `CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus()` can cause some confusion because it looks very much like a constructor (given the class's name `CaseUpdateWithDuplicateStatus1`). You would not perform handler logic in a constructor. It's very common in handler classes to use methods like

```
void onBeforeInsert(List<someSobject> newList);
```

to clearly identify the logic being executed in each trigger event.

Your test class for this code would be fairly straightforward. If you have not already, please take the time to complete [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing) on Trailhead. To get you started, I will sketch the logic in words for how I would test this code.

1. Set up data by creating and inserting three Cases with subjects 'A', 'B', and 'C'.
2. In your unit test, create a `List<Case>`. Populate that list with three Cases whose subjects are 'B', 'C', and 'D'.
3. Insert those cases.
4. Re-query those three Cases to get their updated `Status` value.
5. Assert that Cases 'B' and 'C' have been updated to Duplicate.
6. Assert that Case 'D' has not been updated to Duplicate.

That gets you a positive and a negative test case for this functionality.